# Are PHP functions objects?

Tags: php, oop

Is there a built-in class `function` which instances are the standard PHP functions? Are PHP functions objects?

In Python I can test it in this way:

```
from inspect import isclass
def foo():
    pass
isclass(type(foo))
>>> True
```

What about this function in PHP:

```
function foo(){
    return null;
}
```

Comment: User defined functions such as your `foo` example are not a class in PHP, but a language construct. Pretty much like `if` or `interface`. As Carlos pointed out, PHP automatically transforms a function assigned to a variable into an instance of the class Closure.

Answer (score 6):

Anonymous functions are objects of "Closure" class.
Here is the test:

```
$myfunction = function(){
    echo "Hi";
};

if(is_object($myfunction)){
    echo get_class($myfunction); //prints 'Closure'
}
```